# How to attach a PDB file to identify function calls while opening a .DMP file on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, dll, pdb-files, dmp

I have a dump file showing a call stack of the function calls I am trying to identify. I have narrowed down to which dll is causing a fatal crash, which created this dump file. I would like to find out what function is leading the application to crash. But looking at the call stack I only see the address of the function. Please see attached.

I have attached the pdb file from Tools->Option->Debugging->Symbols but it isn't displaying the function name.

Could anyone shed some light ?

[image]
Thanks,

Comment: well, maybe there are no symbols for that dll? is it third party dll? If so you need to ask the developers for them

Comment: @user1296153, Do you get any Exception dialog box? Generally you would find the exception code if you have the source code during you get the execution stops: https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC/wiki/Debugging-Stack-Traces-from-Crash-Dumps. So if you could get it, maybe like Paweł Łukasik's suggestion, you have no source code.

Comment: @user1296153, Would you please share the latest information about this issue?